# How to get start week date and end week date from a week number in Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to store start and end week date from week num into variables in Google Scripts in Google sheets, becouse I want to generate name for backup file with week range.

```
function makeCopy() {


var WeekNum = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "w"); 

var StartWeekDate = ......
var EndWeekDate = ......
var DateRange = StartWeekDate + ' - ' + EndWeekDate
var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + ' ' + Date;

}
```

I want variable DateRange to be 29.4.2019 - 5.5.2019

Thank you :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If this is running from a trigger at the end of the week, it's easier to just do some basic math and subtract 7 from the current date, rather than doing the extra math with week numbers.

```
function setDates() {
  var timezone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();

  var tempStartDate = new Date();
  tempStartDate.setDate(tempStartDate.getDate() - 7); //subtract 7 to get date from 1 week ago
  var startDate = Utilities.formatDate(tempStartDate, timezone, 'dd.MM.yyyy');
  Logger.log(startDate);

  var tempEndDate = new Date();
  var endDate = Utilities.formatDate(tempEndDate, timezone, 'dd.MM.yyyy');
  Logger.log(endDate);

  var dateRange = startDate + ' - ' + endDate;
  Logger.log(dateRange);
}
```

Here's what these dates look like from the log:

```
startDate = 25.04.2019
endDate = 02.05.2019
dateRange = 25.04.2019 - 02.05.2019
```

You can then use these variables for the rest of your script.

Comment: Maybe worked in this case but does not answer the question. Working on a similar problem but the job is not scheduled at fixed rates therefore i cannot subtract a hard 7

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does not sufficiently answer the question. You can subtract a date by the amount it takes to reach the previous Monday using formatDate from Utilities. Now you can specify the format ("u", as explained by [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) ) to return the day of the week (1-Monday, and so on). Once you know this, you can subtract by an appropriate number of days. Here's an example ---

```js
function getMonday(date){
  var d = Number(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), "EST", "u"));
  if(d == 1) return date;
  else{
    // subtract by d-1 days
    return new Date(date.getTime()-(d-1)*(24*3600*1000));
  }
}
```

The timezone can be set appropriately. This is perhaps not the fastest, but gets the job done.